# Проблема с вводом числового значения с помощью scanf()?

Tags: c

> Валя и Вера на своем садовом участке собрали А кг клубники. Из них В кг собрала Вера. Кто из девочек собрал клубники больше и на сколько? Пожалуйста, не ругайте, я только учу С) помогите решить...

Я написал примерно такой код:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main ()
{
    double a, b;

    scanf ("%d%d", &a, &b);
    if (a>b)
        printf("%lf > %lf ", a, b);
    else
        printf("%lf < %lf ", a, b);
    getch();
}
```

Подскажите, что не так? )

Comment: В дополнение к ответу - а как же вопрос на сколько? Да и кто больше тоже не сказано, сказано какое из чисел больше, а это не ответ на поставленный вопрос

Comment: `int main ()`, а не `void main ()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В строке

```
scanf ("%d%d", &a, &b);
```

указаны неверные типы данных, надо так

```
scanf ("%lf%lf", &a, &b);
```

Формат %d применяется для целых (тип int).

Comment: Пробел в стоку формата добавлен необоснованно. Можно просто `scanf("%lf%lf", &a, &b);`.

Comment: @AnT Спасибо! Поправил.